# custom formula in pivot table google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, pivot-table

I'm trying to filter on a value in a call in a pivot table.

In my "config" tab I have the following data:

[image]

In my source data tab I have the following date:

[image]

And in my pivot table I have two filters with custom formula:

- Year (formula: = config!B3)
- Month (formula: = config!B2)

The problem is with the month filter. If I filter on that, no results are shown. The year parameter works.

You can find the sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gps1gYJqUIk6mTGfLc9h7jwhr83SKz2IL0oPIFSZWvQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your custom formulas to

- Year formula: `='time tracking'!A2:A=config!B3`
- Month formula: `='time tracking'!B2:B=config!B2`